# Converting uint8_t hex to string hex in C

Tags: c, string, hash, converters, uint8t

In this case, i use an algorithm hashing to implementating blockchain, and then my algorithm is working properly but the output need to return string. This is my function to try only print the output hexadecimal but i still got an uint8_t:

```
uint8_t output[32]
void print_output(uint8_t* x){
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < 32;++i)
        printf("%02x",x[i]);
}
void hashing(char* string) {
    gimli_hash(string, strlen(string), output, 32);
    print_output(output);
}
```

my output from hashing proses is maybe about like this

`uint8_t output = [0x4a, 0xfb, 0x3f, 0xf7, 0x84, 0xc7, 0xad, 0x69, 0x43, 0xd4, 0x9c, 0xf5, 0xda, 0x79, 0xfa, 0xcf, 0xa7, 0xc4, 0x43, 0x4e, 0x1c, 0xe4, 0x4f, 0x5d, 0xd4, 0xb2, 0x8f, 0x91, 0xa8, 0x4d, 0x22, 0xc8]`

my expectation output is return string value:

`"4afb3ff784c7ad6943d49cf5da79facfa7c4434e1ce44f5dd4b28f91a84d22c8"`

I've tried various ways from stackoverflow that recomend from google search but still can't find what I need. I apologize in advance because I'm not good at C programming language. Please help me so i can finish my project from my teacher.

Comment: Use `sprintf()` to write to a string instead of using `printf()` to write to the terminal.

Comment: Please [edit] an show a [mcve] along with expected vs. actual output. And what are those _"various ways"_ you tried? Maybe showing one or two of them might be a good idea

Comment: i need to return string value because the data will save into json type using python. So the algorithm will wrap into library python. @Barmar

Comment: I understand that. Create the string with `malloc()`, then write to it with `sprintf()`, then return it.

Comment: can you give me some example? @Barmar